# Setting the bounds of double integrals

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Assume $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ have joint probability distribution function

$$ f(y_1, y_2) = \begin{cases}
ke^{-4y_1 - 6y_2} , & y_2 > y_1 > 0 \\
0 , & \text{else}
\end{cases} $$

This is how I set the bounds of the integral based on the condition $y_2 > y_1 > 0$
\begin{align*}
  \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \int_{0}^{y_1} ke^{-4y_1 - 6y_2} \,dy_2 \,dy_1 
\end{align*}

I am not sure if the above setup on bounds is correct since $Y_{2}$ is the upper bound and $0$ is the lower. My thought was integrating over $Y_{1}$ to $Y_{2}$ for the outer integral $dy_{1}$ when $y_{1}$ is fixed; then integrating over $0$ to $y_{1}$ when for the inner integral $dy_{2}$ when $y_{2}$ is fixed. Can someone tell me if my thought process is correct?

Comment: @Mattos, thanks for editing. I am pretty new to Latex syntax. Can you tell me if there is editor in StackOverflow where I could practice typing these mathematical symbols in latex for posting questions in general?

Comment: You can just practice by answering questions on this site, or you can download a latex editor and start using that. A good latex editor to begin with (I think anyway) is [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/). Also, you can look at the [MathJax website](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for guidance about typesetting on math stackexchange.

Comment: What are you trying to do by integrating? The correct bounds could change depending on your answer.

Comment: @ZachBoyd I am trying to find **k** by integrating the following: \begin{align*}
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ke^{-4y_1 - 6y_2} \,dy_2 \,dy_1 
\end{align*} by setting it to 1. Hence, I needed to find the bounds first before I go ahead solving for **k**.

Comment: Ok. My guess is that what you really mean is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y_1,y_2) dy_2 dy_1$, since what you wrote is undefined. Then finding $k$ so that it is a proper probability density function. In that case, the approach in the accepted answer seems about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Generally in these situations, the inner integral will have bounds that depend on the outer integration variable and the outer integral with have constant bounds. This way, the inner integral that you do first is a function of the outer integral's integration variable. Then you can do the outer integral and get a number (since it has constant bounds). Your expression doesn't even make sense. What is that $y_2$ on the outer integral? We've already integrated over $y_2$ and it makes no sense that the answer would depend on its value: it has no value, it was a dummy integration variable. And what about the $y_1?$ It's both in the limits and it's the integration variable. First, expressions like $\int_0^x f(x)dx$ are frowned upon, even when the intended meaning is clear. And in this case, your answer should be a number, not a function of $y_1,$ anyway.

So to get the bounds right, we can set up the inner integral first, which is over $y_2.$ We see we have support $y_2>y_1>0.$ This means our integral should only go over the region where $y_2>y_1.$  Thus we have bounds $\int_{y_1}^\infty dy_2$ for the inner integral.

Then the outer variable $y_1$ is allowed to range from $0$ to infinity since we have $y_1>0$. Sure it has to be less than $y_2$ but we already took care of that in the inner integral. There's no such thing as $y_2$ anymore: we already integrated over it.

So the correct setup is $$ \int_0^{\infty}\int_{y_1}^\infty k e^{-4y_1-6y_2}\;dy_2dy_1.$$

Comment: I knew you already explain quite clearly above but I am still pretty shaky on finding the right bounds when it comes to solving these types of problems in general. What will be the first approach to take before hasting to setting up the bounds when solving problems similar to this?

Comment: I'd prefer to set it up like this $$ \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{y_2} f(y_1,y_2) dy_1 \ dy_2 $$ since $y_1$ is bounded and $y_2$ isn't. One fewer infinity to deal with

Comment: @NateLee Hard to give general advice here. Pick one variable and make it the "inner" integration variable. See if you can figure out based on the inequalities what the bounds are supposed to be. Then try the other variable and see if it looks any better. Then once you've set up the inner integral, do the outer one.